# Extract digits to the right of the decimal point

Tags: matlab, double

e.g. x = 12.354

I want to get 354 from x. For this I tried this equation,

y = x - floor(x)

But this generates 0.354 which is not my requirement.

So, how can I do it?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I have to use MATLAB. But I don't know how to do it. Is floor available in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic idea as pointed out by @JoachimPileborg looks like this in MATLAB:

```
x = 12.354;
str = num2str(x);
idx = find(str=='.');
substr = str(idx+1:end);
y = str2num(substr);
```

Comment: @Emtiaj please consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/287333) in order to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution that should work with all programming languages, is to convert the number to a string, then take the sub-string from after the decimal point (or comma) and convert it to an integer.

Comment: Those real values are the output of a function. So the question is how to convert this to string. [Using MATLAB]

Comment: I got my answer. Thank you pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (possibly faster) to m.s. 's answer.  Notice the 'shift' due to this approach effectively removing the zeroes to the right of the decimal point.

```
yfoo = 34.00267400;
yfoo = yfoo- floor(yfoo);  % .00267400;
% internal rep of number ignores trailing zeros.
yrab = str2num(strrep(num2str(yfoo),'.','')); %2674
```